# Добавление ViewPager номерного индикатора

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpageindicator

Есть `ViewPager` который нужен для перелистывания картинок, нужно добавить в него индикатор, который при перелистывания элементов будет менять номер, пример такого индикатора приведён ниже, как его сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну можно поискать какую-нибудь либу предоставляющую именно такой дизайн viewpageindicator.
Если не удастся то можно создать TextView как на дизайне. Потом к вашему ViewPager добавить:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           textview.setText(String.format("%d/%d", position, count; ))
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

где count количество страниц вашего view pager